Use pretrained model with insanely fast whisper
I am trying to use a custom model with insanely fast whisper.
This is the code that I have so far:
...
    def __init__(self):
        self.insanely_fast_whisper_model = PreTrainedModel(
            config=PretrainedConfig(name_or_path=WHISPER_MODEL_PATH),
        )
...
    async def _transcribe_insanely_fast_whisper(self, file_content: bytes = None) -> str:
        pipe = pipeline(
            "automatic-speech-recognition",
            model=self.insanely_fast_whisper_model,  # "openai/whisper-large-v3",
            device="cpu",  # "cuda:0",  # or mps for Mac devices
            model_kwargs={"attn_implementation": "flash_attention_2"}
            if is_flash_attn_2_available()
            else {"attn_implementation": "sdpa"},
        )

        outputs = pipe(
            file_content,
            chunk_length_s=30,
            batch_size=24,
            return_timestamps=True,
        )
        return outputs

I've tried many things but whenever I am running the code I am getting:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py", line 1097, in pipeline
    return pipeline_class(model=model, framework=framework, task=task, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/automatic_speech_recognition.py", line 210, in __init__
    feature_extractor._processor_class
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_processor_class'

I don't know a lot about models and transformers and how to use them. Tried reading the documentation but didn't find an answer.
Additionally here is the directory structure that WHISPER_MODEL_PATH is pointing to, for what it's worth:
.
├── dataset
│   └── whisper-large-v3-ro-ct2
│       ├── config.json
│       ├── preprocessor_config.json
│       ├── tokenizer.json
│       └── vocabulary.json
├── Dockerfile
├── readme.md
└── setup_python.sh

Please, let me know if you need any additional info.
